# run a single task on a bare bones operating system

Tags: bootloader, bare-metal

I would like to cross compile an ansi c program from linux for a the barest bare boned operating system that can read a single file and write to a single file on an x86. Then I would like to reboot into that bare os, and run that single program.   What are my choices ?

Comment: Curious... why would you like to do that? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I have a some petabytes of radiology imaging data that I would like to do feature extraction on... So I'll need networking support to a san device.  Mostly I want to experiment and learn something, but I think the efficiency gains may be worth it if I do other things with the data on a regular basis.